# zookeeper and hadoop 2.6 + hbase 0.98

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

In hadoop 2.6 with hbase 0.98 is needed to install zookeeper explicitly ? because when I run hadoop and hbase I have a process named "HQuorumPeer" and I think this is zookeeper. Do hbase include zookeeper or I should install it seperately ?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.quora.com/Do-I-have-to-install-Zookeeper-separately-even-for-HBase-Standalone-or-is-it-in-built-with-HBase-setup

If you are in Standalone mode, you don't need to, otherwise it can be better to install it on a diffrent cluster.